# Unable setting nested json data on localstorage in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, local-storage

I have problem to setting nested json data on localstorage in sencha.

I have Store class:

```
 Ext.define('default.store.Top25Store',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store', 
config:
{
    autoLoad:true,
    model: 'default.model.Top25WordFinal',    
    id:'TodaysWord',
    proxy:
    {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://alucio.com.np/trunk/dev/sillydic/admin/api/word/my_favourite_words_with_definition/SDSILLYTOKEN/650773253e7f157a93c53d47a866204dedc7c363', 
        reader:
        {
                type:'json',
                rootProperty:''
        }
    }
}
});
```

and model class:

```
Ext.define('default.model.Top25WordFinal', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: ['default.model.Top25WordRaw'],

    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'status', mapping: 'status'},
            {name: 'message', mapping: 'message'},
            {name: 'name', mapping: 'name'},
            {name:'data', mapping: 'data'},
            {name: 'definition', mapping: 'definitions.definition'},
            {name: 'ratings', mapping: 'definitions.rating'},
            {name:'def_id', mapping:'definitions.def_id'},
        ],
    }
});
```

and associated model class:

```
Ext.define('default.model.Top25WordRaw', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
        'name',
        'author',
        'word_id',
        'category',
        'definition',
        'rating',
        'def_id',
        'example',
        'author',
        'is_favourite'
        ],
        belongsTo: "default.model.Top25WordFinal"
    }
});
```

Model that can used in offline:

```
Ext.define('default.model.Top25WordRawOffline', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: ['default.model.Top25WordOffline'],

    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'status', mapping: 'status'},
            {name: 'message', mapping: 'message'},
            {name: 'name', mapping: 'name'},
            {name:'data', mapping: 'data'},
            {name: 'definition', mapping: 'definitions.definition'},
            {name: 'ratings', mapping: 'definitions.rating'},
            {name:'def_id', mapping:'definitions.def_id'},
        ],
        identifier:'uuid', // IMPORTANT, needed to avoid console warnings!
    proxy: {
      type: 'localstorage',
      id  : 'Top25Display'
    }
    }
});
```

Where **default.model.Top25WordOffline** is just like **default.model.Top25WordRaw**.

View that display accurate format:

```
store: 'Top25Store',
       itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
           '<div>',                
           '<tpl for="data">',
           '<ul class="parabox">',
           '<li><h2 ><b>{name}</b> </h2>',                          
           '<tpl for="definitions">',
           '<ul class="para-box-wrapper">',
           '<li class="{rating}"><div id = "definition" class="{rating}">','{definition}',
           '<span class="authorBox"><i>Author: {author}</i></span>',
           '<div id = "favourite" class="{is_favourite}" ></div>',
           '</li>' ,
        '</div>',
        '</ul></li>', 
        '</tpl>',
        '</ul>',
        '</tpl>',
        '</div>'
        ),
```

I got value on view. but  Problem to store in localstorage: in controller,

```
localStore.getProxy().clear();
         store.each(function(record) {
         var rec = {
         message : record.data.message,
         definition : record.data.definitions.definition,
         ratings:"red"
         // defintion:record.data.definitions.def_id
        };

        localStore.add(rec);
        localStore.sync();
```

I have set message on localstorage and static ratings but problem in definition. How to store definitions, please clearfy.

Comment: post default.model.OnlineFinal code and store you looping through is default.store.News.. am i right ?

Comment: please check my edited new store, i have post wrong store.

Comment: can i see model used in localStore ?

Comment: please check my problem.i added new offline storage model.

Comment: there seem to be some different spellings of `definition`, `defintion` - did you try and clear those up? What is the actual problem?

Comment: i have done, change from defintion to definition, still problem in my head. please check out my problem once again.

Comment: what are the data you want store using Top25WordFinal model

Comment: your model design confusing me.. what you trying achieve using that model

Comment: please see my JSON, http://alucio.com.np/trunk/dev/sillydic/admin/api/word/my_favourite_words_with_definition/SDSILLYTOKEN/650773253e7f157a93c53d47a866204dedc7c363 ,  would you have alternative model class for this? I am trying to get word with defination.

Comment: yes, i saw that.. what are data you want to store in online store and what are data you want to store in offline store ?

Comment: Everything on online but an offline i want o store word, status, definition, ratings, def_id. but in my code message store in local but not others.

Comment: ok viswa, I hope you can.

Comment: Top25Store loaded all data successfully ?

Comment: @Viswa, in Top25Store data loaded successfully, where i have done display all data successfully in view. you can see on view.

Comment: I have also post pictorial form , would you like to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397623/how-to-get-value-form-record-in-sencha-touch

Comment: which definition you want to get.. there 5 definition in that json

Comment: @Viswa, one word may have multiple definition, i want all definition to store in localstorage. is there any problem for all definition store in localstorage.How much data to be storageable in local storage.

Comment: your model code are very strange and i can post code for storing data for online store (better than your way) but i am not sure you can store that must data in localStorage or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
var rec = {
         message : record.data.message,
         definition : record.data.definitions.definition,
         ratings:"red"
         // defintion:record.data.definitions.def_id
        };
```

to

```
var rec = Ext.create('default.model.Top25WordOffline', 
         {
             message : record.data.message,
             definition : record.data.definitions.definition,
             ratings:"red"
         });
```